# for loop initialization failure

Tags: c, for-loop, indexing, initialization

I am trying to set index for the `for` loop to go over a char array.
For some reason when I go to debug mode I see the variable `i` (I use it as index in the `for` loop) initialized to 0
and the step is `i++` instead of `i--`.

Using `ddd` debugger on ubuntu.

I tried to set `i` to a constant and failed.[image: in the image you can see the second iteration of the loop and the value for i supposed to be i=32]

Comment: Please do not post images of code, but rather post it as formatted text. [ask]

Comment: See also: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You have UB (undefined behavior). You're going one _beyond_ the end. Try changing `for (i = num_bits; i >= 1; i--)` into `for (i = num_bits - 1; i >= 1; i--)`

Comment: Also, it appears that your bit strings are big-endian. Most people use little-endian because the math is much easier. Also, using `pow` is _wasteful_

Comment: It is usually best to disable optimization when you compile code that you intend to run in a debugger.  If your compiler is indeed reversing your iteration order then compiling with optimization disabled will very likely make it not do so.

Comment: Further, I think `pow(2*Bin_Rep_sum[i],i)` is wrong. Do you want: `Bin_Rep_sum[i] * pow(2,i)`???

Comment: ... or, without `pow()`, `Bin_Rep_sum[i] << i`?

Comment: _Side note:_ If you put _all_ your code in a code block here, others (i.e. I) could write an answer instead of comments.

Comment: Why are you using digit *characters*, `'0'` and `'1'`, instead of the corresponding *numbers*, `0` and `1`?  That appears to be an explicit choice, and it makes your life harder.

Comment: Note that `Bin_Rep_a` and `Bin_Rep_b` are [AFAICT] big-endian (from the first `for` loop). But, `Bin_Rep_sum` is little-endian (from the second `for` loop). So, I question the `for` loop that creates `Bin_Rep_sum`. The endian for all arrays should be the same. And `Bin_Rep_a` and `Bin_Rep_b` have _ascii_ values (i.e. `'0'` and `'1'`) but `Bin_Rep_Sum` is using _binary_ values (i.e. `0x00` and `0x01`). These also should be consistent (and _should_ be binary as John mentioned).

Comment: Copy and paste your source code directly (always without line numbering) and give it code format with Ctrl+K (or toolbar button). That way any reviewer of your case could test the code in his own system.

Comment: Do _not_ post _images_ of code/text or _links_. Images are often chopped. They frequently leave out necessary information. They can't be downloaded/examined. Put code/text in code block(s) here _To create a code block:_ In your editor, select the [desired] text. Copy to clipboard [with `ctrl-c`]. Edit the _question_ here [using the `edit` button]. Scroll to bottom. Enter `\`\`\`` on a separate line [to start a code block]. Then `ctrl-v` to paste in the text. Then, another `\`\`\`` line [to end the code block]. Then, click on the save button.

Comment: We would really like an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For C, we would like a _single_ `.c` file [_with_ (e.g.) `#include <stdio.h>`]. But, _no_ (e.g.) `#include "myprogram.h"`. For runtime errors, it should compile cleanly. We should be able to download, build, and run it on our local systems [if we so choose]. Also ... In separate code blocks: post the program input data that demonstrates the issue, desired/expected output, actual output.

Comment: It would really be useful if that code was shown as text. Now we have to retype everything we want to show you. `num_bits` is too large. `Bin_reps[num_bits] = 0;` is an out of bounds access as the array only allows index `0..num_bits-1`.

Comment: BTW: Is that function really placed in a file `functions.h`? That is not a good idea. You should not put definitinos into headers. Just declarations. Otherwise you will get trouble when you include the same heder in multiple C files.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the top comments, there are a number of issues ...

1. You have UB (undefined behavior). You're going one beyond the end. Try changing `for (i = num_bits; i >= 1; i--)` into `for (i = num_bits - 1; i >= 1; i--)`
2. You are using big-endian for the input numbers but little-endian for the sum.
3. The `a` and `b` vectors use *ascii* values (e.g. `'0'-'1'`) instead of *binary* (e.g. `0x00-0x01`). And, the `sum` vector uses *binary*. These should match.
4. `pow(2*Bin_Rep_sum[i],i)` is wrong. Do you want: `Bin_Rep_sum[i] * pow(2,i)`??? Actually, this is *still* wrong

---

Because the code was posted as an *image*, and was missing some key elements, I had to completely restructure the code. It corrects all of the aforementioned issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned int u32;

#define BITS_PER_BYTE       8
#define BITV_SIZE_INP       (sizeof(u32) * BITS_PER_BYTE)
#define BITV_SIZE_CARRY     (BITV_SIZE_INP + 1)
typedef unsigned char bitv[BITV_SIZE_CARRY];

// uint_to_binary -- convert integer to bit vector
// RETURNS: leftmost one bit(?)
int
uint_to_binary(u32 x,bitv bin)
{

    memset(bin,0,BITV_SIZE_CARRY);

    int bit = 0;

    // store digits from right-to-left (LSB to MSB)
    for (;  x != 0;  x >>= 1, ++bit)
        bin[bit] = x & 1;

    return bit;
}

// my_add -- convert integers to bit vectors and compute bit vector sum
u32
my_add(u32 a,u32 b,bitv bin_sum)
{

    // convert a to bit vector
    bitv bin_a;
    uint_to_binary(a,bin_a);

    // convert b to bit vector
    bitv bin_b;
    uint_to_binary(b,bin_b);

    // zero out the sum
    uint_to_binary(0,bin_sum);

    u32 carry = 0;
    int bit = 0;

    for (;  bit < BITV_SIZE_INP;  ++bit) {
        // get the current digits
        u32 a = bin_a[bit];
        u32 b = bin_b[bit];

        // get the sum of the two numbers plus the carry in
        u32 sum = (a + b) + carry;

        // store the current digit
        bin_sum[bit] = sum & 1;

        // get carry out (for next round)
        carry = sum >> 1;
    }

    // store the final carry out
    bin_sum[bit] = carry;

    return carry;
}

// putbit -- output a single bit
void
putbit(u32 bit)
{
    bit = bit ? '1' : '0';
    fputc(bit,stdout);
}

// my_print -- print a bit vector
void
my_print(bitv bin)
{
    int bit = BITV_SIZE_CARRY - 1;

    putbit(bin[bit]);
    fputc('+',stdout);

    for (bit -= 1;  bit >= 0;  --bit)
        putbit(bin[bit]);
}

// dotest -- show an integer number
void
intshow(u32 x,const char *sym)
{

    putbit(0);
    fputc('+',stdout);

    for (int bit = BITV_SIZE_INP - 1;  bit >= 0;  --bit)
        putbit((x >> bit) & 1);

    printf(" %8.8X %s\n",x,sym);
}

// dotest -- test a single addition
void
dotest(u32 a,u32 b)
{
    u32 sum = a + b;

    // show the original input numbers
    intshow(a,"a");
    intshow(b,"b");
    intshow(sum,"sum");

    // get the sum
    bitv bin_sum;
    my_add(a,b,bin_sum);

    // show the bit vector sum
    my_print(bin_sum);
    printf(" bin_sum\n");

    printf("\n");
}

int
main(void)
{

    dotest(1,2);
    dotest(2,2);
    dotest(3,7);
    dotest(0xFFFFFFFE,1);
    dotest(0xFFFFFFFF,1);
    dotest(0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the test program output:

```
0+00000000000000000000000000000001 00000001 a
0+00000000000000000000000000000010 00000002 b
0+00000000000000000000000000000011 00000003 sum
0+00000000000000000000000000000011 bin_sum

0+00000000000000000000000000000010 00000002 a
0+00000000000000000000000000000010 00000002 b
0+00000000000000000000000000000100 00000004 sum
0+00000000000000000000000000000100 bin_sum

0+00000000000000000000000000000011 00000003 a
0+00000000000000000000000000000111 00000007 b
0+00000000000000000000000000001010 0000000A sum
0+00000000000000000000000000001010 bin_sum

0+11111111111111111111111111111110 FFFFFFFE a
0+00000000000000000000000000000001 00000001 b
0+11111111111111111111111111111111 FFFFFFFF sum
0+11111111111111111111111111111111 bin_sum

0+11111111111111111111111111111111 FFFFFFFF a
0+00000000000000000000000000000001 00000001 b
0+00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000 sum
1+00000000000000000000000000000000 bin_sum

0+11111111111111111111111111111111 FFFFFFFF a
0+11111111111111111111111111111111 FFFFFFFF b
0+11111111111111111111111111111110 FFFFFFFE sum
1+11111111111111111111111111111110 bin_sum
```